# Tag wiki double points?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, tag-wiki

I understand that adding content to a tag wiki gets two reputation points.

Today, I appear to get four points (2 x 2) for

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/objectbuilder/info

which I do not understand. Why the double allocation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tag wiki body and the tag wiki excerpt count as two different posts. [You edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9028615/revisions) [both of them](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9028614/revisions); these edits to them were approved separately and each earned you +2 reputation.

Comment: ok, i would have perceived them as a single entity.