# If there is no full tag wiki, can't we use the excerpt?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display the tag wiki excerpt when the tag wiki is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122933/display-the-tag-wiki-excerpt-when-the-tag-wiki-is-empty)

The [wikipedia](/questions/tagged/wikipedia) page currently says:

> The [wikipedia](/questions/tagged/wikipedia) tag has no wiki summary, can you help us create it?

When clicking the "create" link, an except is shown; there isn't just a full wiki.

Can't we use the excerpt when there is no full wiki?

I have just noticed a link in the "Similar Questions" sidebar to a question asking the same thing, but nothing happened there, (except a link that said something new was going to be done. That was said 4 months ago, and it's still like this), so I'm going to be a little naughty and still post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of wiki edit suggestion privileges is to substantially improve it. Therefore, my suggestion would be that it might be okay to use the Tag Wiki Excerpt inside the full Wiki, but only if you plan to substantially improve it.

Substantially improving a tag wiki involves adding example questions, listing situations when one might plan to use the tag, when not to use the tag, and showing examples of the topic that the tag discusses.

If I saw a Tag Wiki that was simply copied from the excerpt, I would reject it, unless more details are added the qualify as a substantial improvement. However, I can't remember at the moment if the Wiki and the Excerpt are shown together.

They are in fact [separately approved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120471/tag-wiki-double-points).

Additionally, I believe that adding the excerpt to the Tag Wiki itself, either manually or automatically, could marginally discourage other users from improving it further. I recently made improvements on a tag excerpt that had no wiki whatsoever and left the body incomplete with a few links. I personally felt like leaving the main Tag Wiki incomplete motivated me to come back later with more research, and fill in all of the missing details.

A gaping, empty hole screams "improve me" a lot louder than something that already has some content in it, IMHO.

Comment: He's not asking if we're allowed to copy the excerpt to the full wiki. He's requesting that if there is no full wiki, but there is an excerpt, that it automatically use the excerpt in that space rather than saying there's no full wiki.

Comment: @animuson - It's not *really* clear in the question, since the op uses "we" as in "Can 'we' use the tag wiki excerpt." Still, I added more details on what I think about even automatically copying the excerpt. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I did mean what animuson said, and I see what you mean about the empty hole, I guess this really is what made me edit it.